# custom NSView crash when changing the background color

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview

I have a custom NSView object with a retained property named bgColor. I override the setter method by defining setBgColor method:

```
- (void)setBgColor:(NSColor *)theColor
{
    [bgColor autorelease];
    bgColor = [theColor retain];
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

I also have another function called isOnline:

```
-(void)isOnline:(BOOL)connected{
    if(connected){
        self.bgColor = onlineBackgroundColor;
    } else {
        self.bgColor = offlineBackgroundColor;
    }
}
```

When I called the isOnline method in initWithFrame method using `[self isOnline:NO]`, it works fine. But when I try to call isOnline method from a controlling object with:

`[theCustomedView isOnline:YES];` or `theCustomedView.isOnline = YES;`

It would crash in the setBgColor method at the line: `bgColor = [theColor retain];` The complier complains Program received signal: "EX_BAD_ACCESS". I can't figure out why. Was that autorelease wrong?

If so, how come I can call from the controlling object `[theCustomedView setBgColor:aColor];` and from self in the initWithFrame and it would work fine?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to send `-retain` to `theColor` after it's been destroyed.  Check where it's coming from.

Comment: Thank you, that was it! I declared two NSColor variables in the initWitheFrame and forgot to retain them.